# Run/Run Out with dropped bat

Tags: rules, cricket

If a batsman drops his bat while running, and crosses the crease without it - does his team still get a run?

Similarly, if he makes it passed the crease, if the fielding team hits the wickets, is he out since he does not have all his equipment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If a batsman drops his bat while running, and crosses the crease without it - does his team still get a run?

Yes. [Law 18 of Cricket](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs/) makes no mention that the bat has to accompany the player for a run to be completed, simply that the batsman has to be grounded.

> Similarly, if he MAKES it passed the crease, if the fielding team hits the wickets, is he out since he does not have all his equipment?

No. [Law 30](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-30-batsman-out-of-hisher-ground/) states the following:

> A batsman shall be considered to be out of his/her ground unless **some part of his/her person** or bat is grounded behind the popping crease at that end.

It seems that the only downside to dropping your bat while running is that you simply have slightly less reach to ground yourself with. Beyond that, the bat is mostly not necessary for running. I was expecting to find a rule regarding equipment being left "in play" on the field, but it seems that these laws only refer to the fielding side's equipment, and not the batsmen.

Comment: Doesn't the *'However...direction'* quote above actually say that the batsman *cannot* be out if they drop their bat *after* crossing?  Perhaps the highlight should be applied to *continued movement in the same direction* instead of *between the bat and person*, to make your point...

Comment: In any case, +1 for answering my own question *Why are batsmen who celebrate centuries by jumping in the air not at risk of run out, due to no longer being grounded?* before I actually asked it!!

Comment: @jimbobmcgee yeah agreed, on re-read that was very misleading. I've simply removed that quote entirely, since I don't think highlighting the possibility of being "ungrounded" on dropping the bat after reversing direction is relevant to this question (as the implication is that you're going for another run, and thus you're no longer grounded either way). Thanks for calling me out on that!